# Can't find family using glmer in R

Tags: distributions, lme4-nlme, glmm, jmp

*update*
The question is that I have some datas, includes:
region/ animal id/ year/ gender/ environment's noise value/  environment's illumination value/ cort1

and I would like to know whether the data I have: the environment's noise and illumination value will affect animals stress value (the cort1 I mentioned)

Because cort1 isn't normal distribution, and I would like to add random effects (like region, animal id ,year...etc)and I have oversampling individuals,so I would like to use glmm for statistics .

But I have a problem using GLMM ->>> glmer() funtion in R
I have data name cort1,
they are continuous numbers with one decimal place

And I use JMP [image]
to find that it fits SHASH distribution the most,
but there isn't SHASH distribution for glmer family to choose!
What should I do next?
Should i change distribution to fit others

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation,  so please make this a more statistical question by including details and context of your data analysis

Comment: I do think this is a statistical question, something like "what distribution to use" rather than one about R specifically. Like @kjetilbhalvorsen I suggest you edit the question to make that clearer.  Or, if it really is about R, then you can ask on a site that's devoted to R or to software.

Comment: thank you for answering ! i updated it, i'm not sure if these clearly enough!

Comment: thanks peter!! i will search some r asking site !!!

Comment: The `gamlss` package supports the SASH distribution.

Comment: Thank you coolserdash! it helps me a lot ! wish you have a nice day